# ERROR This version of viv.geo contains errors, upgrade required in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I created a function that shows the current location in text using viv.geo.

Version 9.27.9 worked fine before, but now it shows an error.

[image]

The 9.27.9 version is also available on the bixby developers homepage.

[image]

How can i fix it???

Comment: and my bixby studio version is latest version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in the upcoming Bixby Capsule SDK release targeted between 2/18 and 2/28.

In the meantime, there is a workaround explained in this [article](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500001601982) in the [Bixby Developers Help Center](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us) that should get you unblocked. Please note all simulator settings will be reset as this workaround resets your local workspace.

If you continue to experience this issue after the release, please contact us via the "Contact Support" option in Bixby Developer Studio's "Help" dropdown menu.